# PHP upload_max_filesize

Tags: php, file-upload

I've a problem with php file upload.
In my php.ini 'upload_max_filesize' is set to 4mb.
When i try to upload a file bigger than that I never get the UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE error as expected, but the page show the form again without any information about the file ($_FILES is empty).
What's the problem? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: With files below 4mb everything is ok?

Comment: yes, below 4mb everything is ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check these setting in your php.ini also:
post_max_size, upload_max_filesize and memory_limit in php.ini.
post_max_size should be greater than upload_max_size.

and if these does not solve problem then check here for more details: http://www.satya-weblog.com/2007/05/php-file-upload-and-download-script.html

Comment: Don't forget the webserver itself, e.g. Apache's LimitRequestBody

Answer (score 0):

Why is this a problem? You should always check the files array + use the is_uploaded_file function to make sure the file has been uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked another errors? Perhaps you get another error - maybe UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE and thus you get FILES array empty.

Answer (score 0):

Is the enctype on your upload form set correctly? -> enctype="multipart/form-data" is required for forms that do file uploads.

G

Answer (score 0):

See my answer to a similar question; It sounds like the same issue:

[Why dosen't this upload script work with mp4s, mpegs (and maybe any /large/ files)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3941709/why-dosent-this-upload-script-work-with-mp4s-mpegs-and-maybe-any-large-files/3941837#3941837)