# PHP upload_max_filesize not obeyed

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, upload

PHP `/etc/php.ini` is not obeying upload_max_filesize

Details:
using `<?php echo phpinfo(); ?>` I can see that the 'Loaded Configuration file' is /etc/php.ini

Within this file I have the values:

```
file_uploads = On
upload_max_filesize = 12M
post_max_size = 12M
```

BUT 
the phpinfo(); shows upload_max_filesize 2M

After restarting Apache serveral times this value is never obeyed whatever I change the upload_max_filesize and max_post_size.

I have worked around this issue by using a .htaccess directive

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 12M
php_value post_max_size 12M
```

This has allowed the upload value to be changed and the PHPINFO() now shows the value correctly.

```
Directive            Local Value    Master Value
upload_max_filesize  12M            2M
```

**The question is**: why is the /etc/php.ini file not being obeyed in the first place?
Running CentOs 5.4 , php 5.3.29
Searched (`grep -inr '2M' *`) in `/etc/php.d/*` with nothing found.

Why is it not listening to the main php.ini file which it says it's using?

Already looked at
[PHP upload_max_filesize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4183658/php-upload-max-filesize)

and
[Changing upload_max_filesize on PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1122418/changing-upload-max-filesize-on-php)

on SO with no success.

--UPDATE--
Search `grep -inr 'upload_max_filesize in /etc/*.ini` and *.conf with only the 12M value being returned.
Searched /etc/httpd/conf/* /etc/httpd/conf.d/ and obviously the root of the virtual host. No special setup in virtual hosts with grep returning 0 results.

```
Additional .ini files parsed
    /etc/php.d/bcmath.ini, /etc/php.d/curl.ini, /etc/php.d/dom.ini, /etc/php.d/fileinfo.ini, 
    /etc/php.d/gd.ini, /etc/php.d/intl.ini, /etc/php.d/json.ini, /etc/php.d/ldap.ini, 
    /etc/php.d/mbstring.ini, /etc/php.d/mcrypt.ini,
/etc/php.d/mysql.ini, /etc/php.d/mysqli.ini, /etc/php.d/pdo.ini, /etc/php.d/pdo_mysql.ini, /etc/php.d/pdo_sqlite.ini,
/etc/php.d/phar.ini, /etc/php.d/posix.ini, /etc/php.d/soap.ini,    /etc/php.d/suhosin.ini, /etc/php.d/sysvmsg.ini, /etc/php.d/sysvsem.ini, etc/php.d/sysvshm.ini,
/etc/php.d/wddx.ini, /etc/php.d/xdebug.ini, /etc/php.d/xmlreader.ini, /etc/php.d/xmlwriter.ini,
/etc/php.d/xsl.ini, /etc/php.d/zip.ini
```

Comment: On the first few line of `phpinfo()` page, it should tell which `php.ini` is being loaded. Search that `php.ini`

Comment: @Raptor : The OP says /etc/php.ini is indeed used.

Comment: Oops. I missed that line

Comment: @Raptor : Thank you anyway. I overlooked the fact that you can look phpinfo() result to see which .ini is used.

Comment: @Raptor : By the way is it possible to have more than one .ini files at the same time. A general one and a customized one which can be used to override the settings of the general one as needed.

Comment: Yes, multiple `php.ini` can be used. More often use is, use `.htaccess` to override some INI settings.

Answer (score 1):

If you examine the first few lines of the `phpinfo()` you can know
which php.ini is loaded.(courtesy @Raptor)

In your question you have mentioned that  /etc/php.ini is indeed the one loaded.

In that case there is a chance that your httpd.conf contains something like below :

`php_value upload_max_filesize somevalue`

This is a global value which will be applied for all the sites.
I guess it may well override the php.ini settings.

Comment: Thanks sjsam, I will take a look at the http.conf and other included conf files to see. I did originally look there (php.conf) but couldn't see anything regarding 2MB limitations... Will take a closer look at the apache side

Comment: Hi sjsam, I've looked in /etc/*.ini /etc/*.conf /etc/httpd/conf/* /etc/httpd/conf.d/* and no reference to 'upload_max_filesize'... + also tried /etc/php.d with no success....

Answer (score 0):

I had the .htaccess in the root of website overriding this value from php.ini.

Answer (score 0):

I lost quite a bit of time trying to figure this out as well.  Turns out that this will happen if you are using php-fpm.  The php.ini file will be read, phpinfo() will tell you that it's been read, but the max filesize value (as well as a few others) will be ignored.

I experienced this with a Centos8 install, and it took me far too long to notice that it was using php-fpm instead of mod_php, so all the arguments to mod_php were being ignored.

Your options are to either install mod_php or just configure php-fpm properly (better).

Answer (score 0):

Try to set in your htaccess file. May be this might help you guys. It's working for me

```
php_value post_max_size 30M
php_value upload_max_filesize 25M
php_value upload_max_size 25M
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I did write in the post that the .htaccess method is a suitable workaround but it does not explain the question of where/which/why the 2MB is coming from... Anyway, suitable workaround using .htaccess.